# Generalization of nilpotency in ring theory?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I found nilpotent element, strong nilpotent element and t-nilpotent element in the literature of ring theory. Are there any other generalization of nilpotency?

Comment: You are looking for more *specializations* of nilpotency? Or actual generalizations? Nothing you gave generalizes nilpotent elements.

Comment: I want to know about actual generalizations. Is there any other concepts like nilpotency?

Answer (score 1):

It is an interesting question, but I can only recommend a few obvious candidates.

Most trivially, all nilpotents are *zero divisors.*

More interestingly, in commutative rings, nilpotent elements are all in the Jacobson radical, so you could view elements of the Jacobson radical as generalizing nilpotency.